# how the following memcpy is beyond array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, memcpy

I have the following code:

```
#define NUM_STUDENTS 20
#define TIME_STUDENTS 10

typedef struct
{
    int name;
    int age;
} Student;

typedef struct
{
    int number;
    int post;
} Contact;

typedef struct
{
      int             number;
      Student         students[TIME_STUDENTS][NUM_STUDENTS];
      Contact         contact[NUM_STUDENTS];
} Master;

typedef struct
{
      int             number;
      Student         students[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_STUDENTS];
      Contact         contact[NUM_STUDENTS];
} Info;

Info info;
Master master;

//fill the data for master

if(NUM_STUDENTS < 10)
{
   memcpy(&info.student[0][0],
         &master.student[0][0],
         sizeof(Student) * NUM_STUDENTS * NUM_STUDENTS);
}
```

the `NUM_STUDENT`S can be modify from `1` to `20`. 
but I got the following warnings:

```
Warning 420: Apparent access beyond array for function 'memcpy(void *, const void *, unsigned int)', argument 3 exceeds argument 2
```

what is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like a typo this `sizeof(Student) * NUM_STUDENTS * NUM_STUDENTS` should be `sizeof(Student) * TIME_STUDENTS * NUM_STUDENTS`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `Master`, you have only

```
Student         students[TIME_STUDENTS][NUM_STUDENTS];
```

and `TIME_STUDENTS` is smaller than `NUM_STUDENTS`, so

```
 memcpy(&info.student[0][0],
       &master.student[0][0],
       sizeof(Student) * NUM_STUDENTS * NUM_STUDENTS);
```

copies more bytes than the source has.

Comment: then how to fix it? if the #define NUM_STUDENTS 20, then I can change the code to sizeof(Student) * NUM_STUDENTS * NUM_STUDENTS, but if it is #define NUM_STUDENTS 5, then the code should be sizeof(Student) * NUM_STUDENTS * NUM_STUDENTS, how to fix it for both conditions?

Comment: How to fix it depends on what the code shall do. You can `memcpy(&info.students, &master.students, sizeof info.students < sizeof master.students ? sizeof info.students : sizeof master.students);` to copy as much of the `master.students` array to the `info.students` array as will fit. Or you can make sure that both arrays have the same size by changing the definition of one of the structs (but then, why would you have two distinct types?). There are many more options, but without knowing what the intended semantics are, I can't guess what the proper way would be.

Comment: what is memcpy(&info.students, &master.students, sizeof info.students < sizeof master.students ? sizeof info.students : sizeof master.students);

Comment: `sizeof info.students < sizeof master.students ? sizeof info.students : sizeof master.students` picks the smaller of the two sizes, perhaps I should have put that separately, `min_size = MIN(sizeof info.students, sizeof master.students);` with `#define MIN(a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))`, so `memcpy(&info.students, &master.students, min_size);` copies all of `master.students` into `info.students` if `master.students` is not larger than `info.students`, and as much as will fit if it is larger.